# How to convert "tensor" to "numpy" array in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to convert a tensor to numpy in the tesnorflow2.0 version. Since tf2.0 have eager execution enabled then it should work by default and working too in normal runtime. While I execute code in tf.data.Dataset API then it gives an error

"AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'"

I have tried ".numpy()" after tensorflow variable and for ".eval()" I am unable to get default session.

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
# tf.executing_eagerly()
import os
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
from model.utils import  get_noise
import cv2


def random_noise(input_image):
  img_out = get_noise(input_image)
  return img_out


def load_denoising(image_file):
  image = tf.io.read_file(image_file)
  image = tf.image.decode_png(image)
  real_image = image
  input_image = random_noise(image.numpy())
  input_image = tf.cast(input_image, tf.float32)
  real_image = tf.cast(real_image, tf.float32)
  return input_image, real_image


def load_image_train(image_file):
  input_image, real_image = load_denoising(image_file)
  return input_image, real_image
```

This works fine

```py
inp, re = load_denoising('/data/images/train/18.png')
# Check for correct run
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(inp)
print(re.shape,"  ", inp.shape)
```

And this produces mentioned error

```py
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('/data/images/train/*.png')
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load_image_train,num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

Note: random_noise have cv2 and sklearn functions

Comment: I have trouble reading your code. Do you always remove all whitespace, even between function definitions? And almost none of your code has anything to do with your problem. Please try to formulate a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Nils, I  have formatted code. code is fully working with tensorflow2.0 and produces the same output and error. please help me with this error.

Comment: provide complete error message

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar When I use tensorname.numpy() it produces `"AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use the `.numpy` method on a tensor, if this tensor is going to be used in a `tf.data.Dataset.map` call.

The `tf.data.Dataset` object under the hood works by creating a static graph: this means that you can't use `.numpy()` because the `tf.Tensor` object when in a static-graph context do not have this attribute.

Therefore, the line `input_image = random_noise(image.numpy())` should be `input_image = random_noise(image)`.

But the code is likely to fail again since `random_noise` calls `get_noise` from the `model.utils` package.
If the `get_noise` function is written using Tensorflow, then everything will work. Otherwise, it won't work.

The solution? Write the code using only the Tensorflow primitives.

For instance, if your function `get_noise` just creates random noise with the shee of your input image, you can define it like:

```py
def get_noise(image):
    return tf.random.normal(shape=tf.shape(image))
```

using only the Tensorflow primitives, and it will work.

Hope this overview helps!

P.S: you could be interested in having a look at the articles "Analyzing tf.function to discover AutoGraph strengths and subtleties" - they cover this aspect (perhaps part 3 is the one related to your scenario): [part 1](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/03/21/dissecting-tf-function-part-1/) [part 2](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/04/03/dissecting-tf-function-part-2/) [part 3](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/tf.function/2019/05/10/dissecting-tf-function-part-3/)

Comment: 'def get_noise(image)' function is not written in tensorflow. This function's implementation has OpenCV, sklearn and other libraries. Can you suggest me any method by which I can call get_noise function in the tensorflow execution?

Comment: If you want to add random noise to an image, the function I wrote previously (the get_noise` can be used in the pipeline as: `image = image + get_noise(image)`

Comment: So this actually means that if I want to use a custom library for image augmentation, like albumentations, I will not be able to use it, right, due to the tensorflow constraints.

Comment: Yes, or better, you can wrap your augmentation step into a `py_func` call and use it inside your data processing pipeline. All the content of the `py_func` won't be converted to graph code (because tensorflow has no idea about how to convert to nodes these kinds of operations), but your pipeline will be fine. I suggest to do your data augmentation step into a py_func, then invoke the .cache() method of tf.data.Dataset so the cache into actual tensors the result of the augmentation and thus remove any python bottleneck

Comment: Very comprehensive response, thank you very much. Appreciate it.

Comment: Not helpful, the question was how to transfer a tensor to numpy in tf 2.0 which doesn't have  a session (which is an important issue).

Comment: You're wrong @mcExchange. tf.data.Dataset object works in graph mode, not in eager mode. That's why this issue is present. You can't call the .numpy() method on a tensor inside a method that's going to be graph-converted. The same happens if you invoke the .numpy() method on a tensor that's used inside a function decorated with tf.function.

Answer (score 0):

In TF2.x version, use `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)`.