# How to read custom binary files in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a piece of code to read some binary files which are written in a specific format. I want to write a tensorflow version of my `read_file()` function. Is there any way to do so? I **don't** want to wrap my function using `tf.py_function()`.

```py
def read_file(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    w = int(np.fromfile(f, np.int32, count=1))
    h = int(np.fromfile(f, np.int32, count=1))
    data = np.fromfile(f, np.float32, count=2 * w * h)
    data = np.resize(data, (h, w, 2))
    f.close()
    return data
```

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use [tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/FixedLengthRecordDataset) to read samples encoded with a fixed length of bytes from a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, every python code that you want to use beside the tf* functions must be wrapped inside the `tf.py_function()`.

There is no other way to integrate custom Python code with the TensorFlow specialised functions.

You can find even more details about this at this question: [Is there an alternative to tf.py_function() for custom Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59497372/is-there-an-alternative-to-tf-py-function-for-custom-python-code)

Comment: The key function here is `np.fromfile()`, I couldn't find any Tensorflow alternative for that, are you aware of any? With that, it is easy to convert the whole function.

Comment: What if use use tf.constant(np.fromfile()) to convert it to Tensor?

Comment: Curious about the result, never tried it, tell me :D

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work here. I'm using a wrapped version of `read_file()` to make my `tf.data.dataset`, and trying to speed up the process wanted to avoid using `tf.py_function()` by converting the entire code to tensorflow functions. I guess I need to write my own custom tf op.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I put that link to my question, because there was an answer stating there that you cannot do that.

Comment: @AliSalehi It's frustrating as it seems like such a simple feature. Did you end up implementing you own ops? Any chance you'd like to share?