# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' in Tensorflow 2.1

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tfrecord, tensorflow2.x

I am trying to convert the `shape` property of a `Tensor` in Tensorflow 2.1 and I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

I already checked that the output of `tf.executing eagerly()` is `True`,

A bit of context: I load a `tf.data.Dataset` from a TFRecords, then I apply a `map`. The maping function is trying to convert the `shape` property of one of the dataset sample `Tensor` to numpy:

```
def _parse_and_decode(serialized_example):
    """ parse and decode each image """
    features = tf.io.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
            'encoded_image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'kp_flat': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
            'kp_shape': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([3], tf.int64),
        }
    )
    image = tf.io.decode_png(features['encoded_image'], dtype=tf.uint8)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)

    kp_shape = features['kp_shape']

    kp_flat = tf.sparse.to_dense(features['kp_flat'])
    kp = tf.reshape(kp_flat, kp_shape)

    return image, kp


def read_tfrecords(records_dir, batch_size=1):
    # Read dataset from tfrecords
    tfrecords_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(records_dir, '*'))
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecords_files)
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_and_decode, num_parallel_calls=batch_size)
    return dataset


def transform(img, labels):
    img_shape = img.shape  # type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>`
    img_shape = img_shape.numpy()  # <-- Throws the error
    # ...    

dataset = read_tfrecords(records_dir)
```

This throws the error:

```
dataset.map(transform, num_parallel_calls=1)
```

While this perfecly works:

```
for img, labels in dataset.take(1):
    print(img.shape.numpy())
```

*Edit:* trying to access the `img.numpy()` instead of `img.shape.numpy()` results in the same behavior in the tranformer and the codde just above.

I checked the type of `img_shape` and it is `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>`.

Has anyone solved this sort of issue in new versions of Tensorflow?

Comment: is the shape of `img` completely defined? If its shape contains `None` in any one of the dimensions, then this could happen

Comment: I edited my post to add a bit more context. I'm using `tf.io.decode_png` to parse `img` so I'm guessing that the shape is known, isn't it? Also calling `numpy()`on `img`  instead of it shape give me the same behavior... The weird thing is that all of this does not result in an error if I do this in elements from `dataset.take()` instead of inside the `map`...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you cannot use `.numpy()` inside functions that are mapped onto `tf.data.Datasets`, because .`numpy()` is Python code not pure TensorFlow code.

When you use a function like `my_dataset.map(my_function)`, you can only use `tf.*` functions inside your `my_function` function.

This is not a bug of TensorFlow `2.x` versions, but rather on how static graphs are generated behind the scenes for performance purposes.

If you want to use custom Python code inside a function which you map on your dataset, you have to use  `tf.py_function()`, docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function. There is really no other way to mix Python code and TensorFlow code when mapping on a dataset.

You can also consult this question for further information; it's the exact question that I asked a couple of months ago: [Is there an alternative to tf.py_function() for custom Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59497372/is-there-an-alternative-to-tf-py-function-for-custom-python-code)

Comment: Thanks! I think I can't convert everything from my pipeline to native tensorflow operations as I need to dynamically populate a list based on tensor values.... Do you think I can still gain performance by mapping everything I can in pure tensorflow ops and then doing the dynamic part in  another `map` calling `tf.py_func`?

Comment: You can still gain some performance, but I would benchmark to clearly see the differences/gains/losses in time performance.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Is there a way to inspect the value of those tensors inside the function? For debug purposes

Comment: Yes. There is tf.print() instead of pure Python print(), one easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

To expand the answer of Timbus Calin further, here's an implementation example for your use case using the `tf.py_function()`. Keeping the transform function you have as it is, you should change the `dataset.map` like this:

```
dataset.map(lambda img, labels: tf.py_function(transform, 
                                               inp=[img, labels], 
                                               Tout=[tf.float64, tf.float32]))
```

Change the output types in `Tout` according to your data.