# Accessing tensor numpy array using `dataset.map()` in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.data.dataset

I am trying to access the numpy array from a tensor object that is processed with https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map.

I get the error: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

When I try to access the tensor as: np_array = tensor.numpy()

While if I use: dataset.take(n), i am able to access the numpy array.

For more clarity on the situation I am facing, here is a short reproducible example of the error in a google colab:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13ectGEMDSygcyuW4ip9zrWaHO3pSxc3p?usp=sharing

Tensorflow version: 2.4.1

**Update**: Adding code in addition to the colab above:

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# This works
def get_spectrogram_and_label_id(file_path):
    spectrogram, label = get_spectrogram(audio) # not showing the function here since it is irrelevant
    return spectrogram, label

# This doesn't!
def get_spec_and_label_time(spectrogram, label):
    time_step_spectrogram = generate_time_step_samples(spectrogram)
    return time_step_spectrogram, label

# I want to manipulate the Tensor by extracting the numpy array as part of the map function
def generate_time_step_samples(tensor):
    np_array = tensor.numpy() # ERROR: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
    # Do something with the numpy array
    return np_array

filenames = ['file1.wav', 'file2.wav', ...]
files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
spectrogram_ds = files_ds.map(get_spectrogram_and_label_id) # this works
spectrogram_time_ds = spectrogram_ds.map(get_spec_and_label_time) # this doesn't
```

More details in the google colab.

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: @NicolasGervais Added code excerpt, with more details in the google colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13ectGEMDSygcyuW4ip9zrWaHO3pSxc3p?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access `.numpy()` inside a `.map()` function.

This is not a bug, it is how TensorFlow works with static graphs behind the scenes.

Read my answer here for a more comprehensive explanation.

[AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' in Tensorflow 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60347349/attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-numpy-in-tensorflow-2-1/60378748#60378748)

Comment: Thanks for the reference @TimbusCalin , this helps.

However, I am struggling to implement what I am trying to do. I tried replacing:
```spectrogram_time_step_ds = spectrogram_ds.map(get_time_step_spectrogram_and_label_id)
```
by
```spectrogram_time_step_ds = tf.py_function(func=get_time_step_spectrogram_and_label_id, inp=[spectrogram_ds], Tout=[tf.int64, np.ndarray])
```
but get `TypeError: Expected DataType for argument 'Tout' not <class 'numpy.ndarray'>.`

I still need to access the numpy array but not sure how

Comment: What happens if you write data type exactly, like np.int32/np.float32?