# how to convert kerastensor to numpy array and vise versa during model building

Tags: numpy, type-conversion, feature-extraction

I am trying to get the activation maps of conv1, convert them to numpy array to do some computations and then convert them back to kerasTensor to feed them to conv2

using below example, could you please help me :pray: :pray:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(48,48,3))
conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
####   here i need to get the activation maps of conv1   ####
pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv1)    

#shape=(None, 64, 24, 24)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv2)
```

i tried `.numpy()` and `eval()` but none of them worked, also i tried to disable `eager_execution` and also didn't succeed.

Please help.